# CBV or Functional View for JsonResponse

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-class-based-views

I am new to creating API endpoints using Django. Which is a better way to handle API requests and  process JsonResponse? Should I do it in a Class-Based View? Or a Functional View?

I would assumed CBV would be an overkill since people tend to use CBV for the generic-view inheritance. Since I am merely sending back a Json object, i would consider it unnecessary and thus a Functional view would suffice. However, I am not too sure what exactly are the other components of CBV and FV that would matter and make the difference.

If there is one view better over another view, can you please tell me with reasons why one is preferred over another.

Cheers.

Comment: The best way to handle API requests is with the tool specialised for the job, Django REST Framework.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, i will go check it out! But my company’s restriction leaves me without such a tool, therefore with that in mind, what would you suggest then?

Comment: One is not better than the other. CBVs are powered by class inheritance, which can be both a good thing (code reuse) and a bad thing (confusing).

Comment: However in terms of Json request processing? Or is there no diff?

Comment: You need to talk to whoever is making pointless restrictions at your company. Why is Django allowed but not DRF? Your project won't get very far if you can't use any of the thousands of third-party libraries.